# Does a Windows Form Application written in Visual Basic require the VB runtime as well?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, runtime

If I make an application in Visual Studio (Windows Form App) and write the code in Visual Basic. After I compile it to .exe do I need vb runtime to run on other PC? Or it runs with no problem as C++ apps do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably came from those old days of VB6 and prior, when you had to install VB runtime on a target machine to run your application. Same as how you install Visual C++ redistributable to run Visual C++ applications these days.

The important thing to understand about .NET is that it does not matter which language you use to write a .NET application. It will only require .NET framework to be installed on the target machine, which has to match the version you are targeting in your application. Of course, if you reference 3rd party DLLs, that's extra, same as any other framework.

This is why you are free to pick the language of your choice, without impacting your development strategy, whether it be VB.NET, C# or [any other .NET language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3a.NET_programming_languages), and you can change it later, if you decide to. There are free converters available to migrate between different .NET languages, which makes it flexible for you as a developer.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to make sure that the machine where you deploy your application has the appropriate .NET Framework installed (the same one you target).

Once the .NET Framework is installed, the only requirements will be your executable and any dependencies you specifically include as extra references in your project (and any those dependencies need).